# Download a file to Google Cloud instead of local disk

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, python-3.10

I'm trying to build a Youtube video to audio converter in Python, and instead of storing the audio file to local disk, I would like to store it in [GCS](https://cloud.google.com/).

The following is my code to download the audio file on disk:

```
import tldextract
from pytube import YouTube
import logging

def Download(video_list):
    for url in video_list:
        logging.info('Url: %s' % url)
        youtube = YouTube(url.strip())
        youtube.streams.filter(file_extension='mp4')
        stream = youtube.streams.get_by_itag('139')
        stream.download('', 'audio.mp3')

video_list = []

run = True

while run == True:
    link = str(input("Enter a YouTube URL or press D to download the video(s): "))
    domain_name = tldextract.extract(link).domain
    if link.lower() == 'd':
        Download(video_list)
        run = False
    elif domain_name == 'youtube':
        video_list.append(link)
    else:
        print("Invalid youtube URL.")
```

Is there any way to store the downloaded directly to Google Cloud without using space on my local disk?

P.S. I know how to upload an audio file to GCS by using the custom created `upload_blob` function; what I want to know is if there is a way I can trick my machine into uploading that audio file directly to the cloud.

Comment: Audio file is small, you can keep it in memory and not write it on your local disk.

Comment: I'm trying to use Whisper on it, to transcribe it and Whisper API needs it to be an audio file; and I'm trying to deploy the whole thing to web; so I can't really use my local disk.